# Fresh Ruby gem from Bundler - cannot load my version.rb file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I wanted to make a fresh Ruby app, so I decided to use `bundle gem foo` to do it. This gave me the whole:

```
lib/
  foo/
    version.rb
  foo.rb
Gemfile
Rakefile
foo.gemspec
README.md
```

structure. Now when I run `ruby foo.rb`, I get:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- foo/version (LoadError)
```

foo.rb is just the default:

```
require 'foo/version'

module Foo
end
```

Can gems not be ran on their own? I hope I don't have to include my gem into a sample app just to test it out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run `bundle exec ruby foo.rb` to use Bundled gems.

Alternatively, you can modify `foo.rb` itself to assume Bundler. Just put

```
require 'bundler/setup'
```

at the top.

Answer (score 0):

What directory are you running that from? I would check your $LOAD_PATH and ensure lib is included in it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter what directory I run it from. Also, doesn't the gemspec cover $LOAD_PATH?

Comment: The gemspec usually does `unshift` the lib folder into it, but if you want to run any code, you'll have to add the lib folder yourself. Some gems/utils (couldn't think of a good name) such as RSpec will add lib and spec to the load path for you.