# Bundler + new gem: cannot load such file -- minion/version (LoadError)

Tags: ruby

I just ran `bundle gem minion` to create a new gem called minion. However, when I try to test it out with `ruby  it is throwing me the error

```
    [~/Documents/minion]$ ruby lib/minion.rb   
    /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- minion/version (LoadError)
        from /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from minion.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

??

lib/minion.rb

```
require "minion/version"
# require "yahoo-finance"

module Minion
end
```

lib/minion/version.rb

```
module Minion
  VERSION = "0.1.0"
end
```

I haven't done anything in this app. What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer

[Fresh Ruby gem from Bundler - cannot load my version.rb file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744921/fresh-ruby-gem-from-bundler-cannot-load-my-version-rb-file)

added `require 'bundler/setup'` to the top of my file